# improving fuel efficiency in a 96 taurus

Tags: fuel-consumption, taurus, dn101

I have a 1996 Ford Taurus with less than 200,00km on it I don't want to spend too much on it but want to improve the fuel efficiency on it. I do mostly highway driving with a bit of city driving. Right now I am getting between 450-500km per tank, I do run my car before I get for about five minutes when its cold out so I know this doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

For the car, keep the tires set at the right pressure, check the alignment, check the brakes on a regular basis, empty any extra stuff out of the car.  As a driver, there are many articles that can be googled on how to get better mileage through various driving techniques.  Mostly they involve speed control and better planning ahead while driving.  Obviously, you already know one place that you're wasting fuel.  :-)

Comment: If this were my answer, I'd have listed checking the tire pressures and emptying your car of junk as points 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.  A car that's driving on squishy tires with a lot of crap in it is burning money.

Answer (score 2):

Fuel efficiency gets brought up fairly frequently (for good reason).  Here are some of the things that I've pointed out in similar questions:

[Engine size doesn't determine fuel efficiency.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1355/57)

[Using the fuel with the correct octane rating is important.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/will-higher-octane-fuel-improve-gas-mileage)

[Making major changes to your car in the name of efficiency is usually not a good idea.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/661/how-to-optimize-fuel-consumption-by-changing-the-rear-differential-ratio)

And, to quote Jeremy Clarkson on the subject, "It isn't what you drive that matters, it's how you drive it."  Considering that he managed to drive a Turbo Diesel Audi from London to Edinburgh and back on the same tank of fuel, I'm willing to give his tips due consideration.

Comment: I agree that if a car is even halfway decently maintained that the driver is by far the most important component!

Answer (score 0):

Another easily checked and often forgotten item is the air filter.Also on the highway keep the windows up to decrease drag.